# Regex question - asp.net iis url rewrite

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

Could anyone help me with this regex issue?

`^(Songs|Albums)$`
becomes
`{R:1}.aspx`

This gives you songs.aspx, albums.aspx

wondering if I can do this in Regex:

`^(Songs|Albums|Songs/List)$`

and how do I get SongsList.aspx from Songs/List?

Thanks!

**Edit** 
This worked:
`^(Songs|Albums)/(List)?$`
`{R:1}{R:2}.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

This worked:
`^(Songs|Albums)/(List)?$`
`{R:1}{R:2}.aspx`